# pull data with HtmlAgilityPack Web Scraping c#

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

What could be the reason that it returns null in selectnodes?

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.wired.com/most-popular/");
var headerNames = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='archive-item-component__title']").ToList();
string listData = "";
foreach(var item in headerNames)
{
   listData += Environment.NewLine + item.InnerText;   
}
Console.WriteLine(listData);
```

Comment: 1. Don't use HtmlAgilityPack, use AngleSharp. 2 Most likely the page is being built with client-side rendering using something like React, so you cannot scrape it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that 'archive-item-component__title' class in the web site is specified for h2 tags, not for a tags.

Selecting your headerNames like this works:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2[@class='archive-item-component__title']");
```

PS: you don't need to call .ToList() on the SelectNodes results, you can loop through the HtmlNodeCollection as is.